# Epic launcher not resuming download

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

I was updating Fortnite yesterday; it was a 2 gb update and I download 700 mb. I paused it and closed the launcher. I opened the launcher the next day, and its donwloading 3 gb again! If I download that, it again increases to 5.26gb, why?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact Epic. If it's a bug, they're the only ones who can fix it. Also, I'm sure they're very interested in knowing about bugs like these and fixing them.

In the meantime, try not to close the launcher before the download is finished. Letting your PC run overnight is likely cheaper than restarting the same download over and over again.